# Where is a loop diagram in Euler-Lagrange equation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, path-integral, perturbation-theory, correlation-functions

In path integral formalism, there is clearly an off-shell configurations of fields as integrated variables. For example,
$$\langle T\{\hat\phi(x) \hat\phi(y)\}\rangle=\frac{\int D\phi \ \phi(x)\phi(y)\exp(iS)}{\int D\phi \ \exp(iS)}.$$

But in canonical formalism, the field operator $\hat\phi(x)$ follows the Euler-Lagrange equation where the off-shell configuration is not clear.

My question is:

1. Where is an off-shell configuration in Euler-Lagrange equation, and how to find off-shell effects in E-L equation?
2. Is it possible to obtain a quantum off-shell effect equivalent to the path integral (like loops in Feynman diagram) by perturbatively expanding Euler-Lagrange equation so as in the classical theory?

As a classical perturbation of E-L eq, I assume such as $$\hat\phi(x)= \hat\phi_{0}(x)+\lambda \hat\phi_{1}(x)+\lambda^{2} \hat\phi_{2}(x)+\dots .$$

If such perturbation is meaningless in QFT, it would be helpful if you could tell me why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In the [canonical/operator formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_quantization) the [Heisenberg equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_picture) are satisfied as operator identities.
2. In contrast, off-shell configurations appear in the [path integral formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation).
3. The [Schwinger-Dyson (SD) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger%E2%80%93Dyson_equation)
   $$\left< \Omega \left| T_{\rm cov}\left\{ F[\phi]\frac{\delta S[\phi;J]}{\delta \phi(x)}\right\}\right| \Omega \right>_J~=~i\hbar\left< \Omega \left| T_{\rm cov}\left\{\frac{\delta F[\phi]}{\delta \phi(x)} \right\}\right| \Omega \right>_J \tag{SD}$$
   display off-shell effects, i.e. when the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)
   $$ \frac{\delta S[\phi;J]}{\delta \phi(x)}~\approx~0 \tag{EL}$$
   are not satisfied. See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74795/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/359961/2451) related Phys.SE posts.