# Confusion regarding time ordering in the Ward Identity derivation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, path-integral, correlation-functions, ward-identity

This question does not follow from reading any text, but I was watching Shiraz Minwalla's CFT lectures on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/mycXDInLqNo?si=Srf6mxCNkxOBfgpl&t=3096). At 51:36 into the lecture, he raises the question that, as an operator statement, we know $$\partial_\mu j^\mu = 0,$$ where $j^\mu$ is a conserved current of the theory. However, we know that the Ward Identities are

\begin{equation}
\langle \partial_\mu j^\mu(x) O_1(x_1)\cdots O_n(x_n)\rangle + \sum_i \langle \cdots O_i(x_i)\delta(x-x_i)\cdots\rangle = 0,
\end{equation}

where $\langle \cdots \rangle$ denote a path integral average. Now he says that this is consistent with the fact that $\partial_\mu j^\mu = 0$ as an operator statement simply because path integral calculates time ordered correlators. He continues to say that "having $\partial_\mu j^\mu$ inside a path integral really means
\begin{equation}
\partial_\mu\langle j^\mu O_1(x_1)\cdots O_n(x_n)\rangle
\end{equation}
i.e. computing the average at two infinitesimally close insertions and then taking the difference, further dividing by the infinitesimal distance between the insertions. Now what I do not understand is how having $\partial_\mu j^\mu$ 'inside' the path integral actually means the above, since if I just pull out the $\partial_\mu$ from the Ward Identities as well, I get something completely different. Is this really just some abuse of notation and I am unnecessarily confused? I hope I was able to explain my question.

Comment: You need to remember that the correlators calculated by  the path integral correspond to  vacuum expectations of time ordered products in the operator language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point is that each correlator $\langle\cdots\rangle$ implicitly contains a covariant time-ordering $T_{\rm cov}$, i.e. time-differentiations inside its argument should be taken *after/outside* the usual time ordering $T$ in the correlator. This is necessary in order to correctly translate between the operator formulation and the path integral formulation, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/359961/2451) related Phys.SE post.