# Time ordered correlator from path integral: equation of motion?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, correlation-functions, propagator, klein-gordon-equation

Consider a Lagrangian $L(\phi)$ for a field $\phi$ (assume it is a free real scalar for simplicity). Then the time ordered propagator can be expressed as a path integral
$$
\langle\Omega|T\{ \phi(x) \phi(x') \}|\Omega\rangle = \int D\phi\ \phi(x) \phi(x') e^{i \int L} .
$$
This is a standard result from Zee's textbook for example.

We know that the time ordered propagator should obey the equation of motion
$$
( -\Box_x^2 + m^2 )\langle\Omega|T\{ \phi(x) \phi(x') \}|\Omega\rangle = \delta(x - x') \ .
$$
I would like to check that the path integral representation of the propagator satisfies the equation of motion.

However, applying $\Box_x$ to the path integral on the RHS of the above, does not seem to give me the right equation. In fact, since $( -\Box_x^2 + m^2 )\phi(x) =0$ it seems like
$$
( -\Box_x^2 + m^2 ) \int D\phi\ \phi(x) \phi(x') e^{i \int L} = 0
$$
This is obviously wrong, but I don't see why. Is it because of the end points on the integral?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296309/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/359961/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It’s potentially worth stating OP’s mistake explicitly: the field $\phi$ in the path integral is an integration variable, and does not a priori satisfy the equation of motion; heuristically, the path integral instructs the user to integrate over *all* possible fields, not just those satisfying the classical EoM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P(\Phi)$ be a polynomial in a set of  field variables $\Phi= \{\phi_1(x), \phi_2(x),\ldots\}$, and
consider a correlation function
$$
\langle{P(\Phi)}\rangle= \frac 1 Z \int d[\Phi] P(\Phi)e^{-S[\Phi]}.
$$
The functional integral over $\Phi$ should be unaffected by a  linear shift in the integration variables $\phi_i(x) \to \phi_i(x) +\delta \phi_i(x)$. We therefore  have
$$
0= \frac 1 Z \int d[\Phi] \left\{\int \delta \phi_i(x) \left(\frac{\delta P}{\delta \phi_i(x)} - P(\Phi) \frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi_i(x)}\right)d^d x\right\} e^{-S[\Phi]},
$$
and hence
$$
0=\left\langle \int \delta \phi_i(x) \left(\frac{\delta P}{\delta \phi_i(x)} - P(\Phi) \frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi_i(x)}\right)d^d x\right\rangle
$$
for any $\delta\phi_i(x)$.  So, for each point $x$ and field $\phi_i$, we have
$$
\left\langle \frac{\delta P}{\delta \phi_i(x)}\right\rangle= \left\langle P(\Phi) \frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi_i(x)}\right\rangle,
$$
which   is the quantum counterpart  of the classical equation of motion$$
\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi_i(x)}=0.
$$

When  the fields in $P= \phi(x_1)\phi(x_2) \cdots \phi(x_n)$ are bosonic
$$
\frac{\delta P}{\delta \phi(x)}= \sum_{k=1}^n \delta(x-x_k)\phi(x_1) \phi(x_2)\cdots \widehat{\phi(x_k)} \cdots \phi(x_n),
$$
where the hat denotes the omission of that factor.

In your case the functional derivative $\frac{\delta S}{\delta \phi_i(x)}$ is the KG equation and you get your equation by taking $P= \phi(x)$ to be a one point function.